# LDAP Search with winldap.h on AD Server

Tags: c++, search, active-directory, ldap, windows-server-2008-r2

I am trying to do a LDAP search and it is not working on my Active Directory Test Server. I use this code:

```
#include <winldap.h>
...
LDAP* ld = ldap_init("AD-servername", 389);
int myVersion =LDAP_VERSION3;
ldap_set_option(ld, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, &myVersion);
ldap_connect(ld, NULL);
//ldap_simple_bind_s(ld, NULL, NULL); I tried using this line too. but got the same error
LDAPMessage *pMsg = NULL;
int retVal = ldap_search_s(ld, "dc=myDomain,dc=extension", LDAP_SCOPE_SUBTREE, "(samAccountName=testaccount)", NULL, NULL, &pMsg);
//retVal = 1 which is LDAP_OPERATIONS_ERROR
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What are the values returned by 'ldap_set_option' and 'ldap_connect'? Have you tried to use only one DN instead of 2? Try to use some simple filter.

Comment: `ldap_set_option` and `ldap_connect` return both `LDAP_SUCCESS`. My actual DN is `dc=dl,dc=intern` which is my domain name -> `dl.intern`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unless otherwise configured, you **must** bind using a valid account name and password for Microsoft Active Directory servers, otherwise it will return the operations error for all queries except [a very small handful](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755809%28v=ws.10%29.aspx).

i.e. that:

```
ldap_simple_bind_s(ld, NULL, NULL);
```

Needs to be replaced with something like:

```
char *username = "cn=aUser,ou=Users,dc=myDomain,dc=extension";
char *password = "this is the password";
ldap_simple_bind_s(ld, username, password);
```