# Operations error : while querying ldap_search_ext_s in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, active-directory, ldap, openldap

I am using ldap for user authentication as mentioned in this link. 
http://www-archive.mozilla.org/directory/csdk-docs/writing.htm 
Here I am getting "Operations error" while ldap_search_ext_s call. Can anyone tell me what changes I need to do in order to get the user information from Active Directory.

Note : I don't want to enter the dc name and password while binding. Since machines will be running under normal users account (domain users) which do not have admin credentials in domain.Please let me know how to do binding in this case also.

My machine details : 
Mac Lion, 64 Bit.
I am trying to connect to Windows Active Directory.

Thanks,
Tausif.

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind with a valid username and password when connecting to a Windows Active Directory server in most cases.

When you're performing your `ldap_simple_bind_s()`, the two `NULL` parameters need to be replaced - the first with the `DN` of the user that is performing the bind, the second with the password for that `DN`.

There's more link detail in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11133752/ldap-search-with-winldap-h-on-ad-server/11134799#11134799)

Comment: Hi Petesh, Thanks a lot for your valuable guidance. Here in my case  clients will not know the domain controller's password since the logged user will be normal user.Still I want to validate the users. So is there any option where there is no need to provide the password and DN name while binding it. Please guide me on this.

Comment: You need permission to access the data that is provided from the Active Directory server - in general for Linux interoperability a 'search only' account is created which supports just this functionality. You *can* make your active directory insecure so that you can search without a username/password but it's generally not done for security reasons.

Comment: If you follow the details on http://www.windowsitpro.com/article/ldap/how-can-i-enable-anonymous-lightweight-directory-access-protocol-ldap-connections-under-windows-server-2003- it should allow you anonymous ldap connections with the windows server (I've not tested it against 2008)