# How to convert this LDAP code from VBS to C++

Tags: c++, winapi, vbscript, active-directory, ldap

I'm trying to come up with a C++ code to enumerate groups that the current workstation is a member of in an Active Directory set-up. I was able to come up with the following Visual Basic script that does exactly what I need:

```vb
'DN for the workstation
cCN = "CN=WorkstationName,CN=Computers,DC=mydomain,DC=local"
Set objComputer=GetObject("LDAP://" & cCN)

Dim strAll
Dim colGroups, objGroup

strAll = ""
Set colGroups = objComputer.Groups
For Each objGroup In colGroups
    strAll = strAll & objGroup.distinguishedName & vbLf
Next

Wscript.Echo strAll
```

and I receive the output as such:

```
CN=Group1,OU=SomeOU,DC=mydomain,DC=local
CN=Group2,OU=SomeOU,DC=mydomain,DC=local
```

The issue is that I can't seem to convert the LDAP stuff to C++.

I'd really appreciate if someone can help me out?

**EDIT:** *The following is as much as I can glean from my C++ knowledge and COM:*

```
// Initialize COM.
CoInitialize(NULL);

LPCTSTR pwszContainerDN = L"CN=WorkstationName,CN=Computers,DC=mydomain,DC=local";

CComBSTR strADsPath = L"LDAP://";
strADsPath += pwszContainerDN;

IADs *objComputer;
HRESULT hr;

hr = ADsGetObject(strADsPath,
    IID_IADs,
    (void**) &objComputer);

if(SUCCEEDED(hr))
{
    //Now how do you do "objComputer.Groups"?
    //Then later "For Each" enumeration, etc.?
}

// Uninitialize COM.
CoUninitialize();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use WinLDAP library. See this [LDAP Search with winldap.h on AD Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11133752/ldap-search-with-winldap-h-on-ad-server).

Comment: If you bind like this, you will use current user identity:
ldap_bind_s(ldap, NULL, NULL, LDAP_AUTH_NEGOTIATE)